# Xcode 7 GM Seed - Cannot submit to App Store for review

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

Today, I have uploaded a binary that was built in **Xcode 7 GM Seed**. Everything is good but when I submit for review the ituneconnect page said :

> Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of
> LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in lmnk.app/lmnk is 9.0 which is greater than
> the maximum allowed value of 8.4. Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app
> updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or
> later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta
> software.

Could you give me a suggestion for this case?

I have received an email from Apple Store: on 09/10/2015

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent submission for "My app ***". To process your submission, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Toolchain - New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect. Choose the new binary on the app’s Details page in My Apps on iTunes Connect, and click Submit for Review.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

That mean's the error come from AppStore's side, so I'm trying to resubmit my app then I will feed back soon.

Comment: I believe, Apple hasn't yet started accepting builds from XCode7 GM. Wait for the official communication(it may take around a day), and then retry submitting.

Comment: I have submitted apps to the app store using the GM build before so it is throwing a small wrench in my release plans as well.  I am hoping they will update itc soon to accept the builds.

Comment: AppStore is fixed, so the binary built on Xcode 7 GM will be received now!

Answer (score 5):

You will be able to submit to the App Store using Xcode 7 GM soon.  Apple usually ships the GM and then will send an email to developers a few days later letting them know that iTunes connect will now accept the iOS 9 builds.

EDIT: Apple should now be accepting iOS9 builds with GM, I just got the email.

Comment: Confirm :D,
After three days waiting for review my app was published on the App Store.
Thanks all,

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you still need to build with Xcode 6.4, and that you can not target MIN OS >= 9.0. Yet.

This should be fixed for the official release of Xcode 7.

Comment: thank you for your reply but I need to build on the Xcode 7 because my application have new iOS 9 features (Spotlight + Universal link)

Comment: Then, you will have to wait a bit before you submit. Didn't Apple send the "Submit your apps today!" e-mail yet?

Comment: Oh, wait, they did on September 12! What gives?

Answer (score 1):

As at the time of this reply, you can build and submit your iOS apps to the AppStore using Xcode 7 GM Seed.

According to the email from Apple Dev:

> To prepare, build your apps using Xcode 7 GM seed, and test with the
>   GM seeds of iOS 9, OS X El Capitan, and watchOS 2. Read the App Review
>   Guidelines and use TestFlight to get feedback before submitting to the
>   App Store.

Read more: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submit/

Comment: I am in the same situation, got the mail and everything but my submitted apps (in testflight at the moment) can't be uploaded because of ''Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software."... they are built with Xcode 7 GM.... I uploaded them before i got the mail, should i rebuild and re-upload?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode(GM) is not available for publishing applications.
So, just wait..

Answer (score 0):

As of now - I can submit versions via XCode 7GM, but none of the submissions pass the "processing" stage. Bitcode is set to "NO".